# WPF DataGrid updating items with .Refresh

Tags: wpf, layout, datagrid

I am using a datagridview to show my own items in it as `List(Of MyStuff)` and it works quiete well. When my class is changing the content the DataGrid does not change. I need to do `DataGrid1.Items.Refresh` and the items becomes updates.

But now my list contains 700 items and the `.Refresh` methode takes about 15 seconds just because one item changed. I've searched for any "UpdateContent" or "RowUpdate" or "RefreshRow" but found nothing. How is the right way to update single Rows?

```vb
Private LCommand As New List(Of MyLogEntry)

Me.dgv.DataContext = Me.LCommand
        Me._LastUpdate = DateTime.MinValue
        Me._CurrentIndex = -1
        Call UpdateDgv()



Private Sub UpdateDgv()
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(AsyncRefresh)
End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshDgvAsync()
    Try
        Me.dgv.SelectedIndex = Me._CurrentIndex
        Me.dgv.ScrollIntoView(Me.dgv.SelectedItem)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If DateTime.Now.Subtract(Me._LastUpdate).TotalSeconds > 60 Then Me.dgv.Items.Refresh()
    Me._LastUpdate = DateTime.Now
End Sub
```

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dgv" Grid.Row="1" RowHeight="20" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ClipToBounds="True" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn         Header="N°"         Binding="{Binding Index}"           Width="SizeToCells"     MinWidth="30" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn     Header="OK"         Binding="{Binding Successfully}"    Width="SizeToCells"     MinWidth="35" IsReadOnly="True"     Visibility="Collapsed"  />-->

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image x:Name="imgState" Source="{Binding StateImageUrl}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>





                <DataGridTextColumn         Header="Logentry"      Binding="{Binding Title}"           Width="SizeToHeader"    MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True"  FontWeight="Bold"                    />
                <DataGridTextColumn         Header="Action" Binding="{Binding Description}"    Width="SizeToCells"     MinWidth="80" IsReadOnly="True"  FontSize="12"       />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn     Header="Available"  Binding="{Binding Necessary}"       Width="Auto"            MinWidth="35" IsReadOnly="True"                    />
                <DataGridTextColumn         Header="Log"        Binding="{Binding Log}"             Width="*"               MinWidth="50" IsReadOnly="False"  FontSize="8" Foreground="Gray"                />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Cooler Username @Nasenbaer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear for me why do you need to refresh your items at all. If you need to observe log entries collection changes then use `ObservableCollection<LogEntry>`, if you need to update cells when something in LogEntry changes then make it observable by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
When you call Refresh on underlying CollectionView all item containers are regenerated. And it takes a lot of time espacially when virtuallization is disabled.

Comment: Ok thanks. Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` most works. But after changing the order by using my ".Sort" class it does not update the content. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sorting collection by your own?

Comment: The MyLogEntry object contains an property as Integer called "Index". In my own sorter, I am sorting in order to this "Index", yes!

Comment: There is builting mechanizm in WPF for sorting - CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(your_collection).SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PropertyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); This soring should be set only once, when underlying collection is created.

Comment: Thats awesome. But. While editing the rows, the sorting should NOT re-sort row. Just after user wants to do. In this case I need a "do sort now" button. Is this possible with your way?

Comment: In this article - http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/ you can find possible ways of preserving correct sorting order after items are edited.

Answer (score 1):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged at your collection.

Instead of having a List use ObserverableCollection<type>.

At any setter of MyLogEntry properties invoke the PropertyChangedEventHandler.

C# code *(no testing)*:

```
public class MyLogEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private object _myProperty;
    public object MyProperty{
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { 
            _myProperty = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name){
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null){
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```